# Counting a row of pandas data frame in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a column to a data frame with the count of matches in another data frame.  For example,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','no','no','no','no'],
                    'B':['L','L','M','M','H','H','L','L','M','M','H','H'],
                    'C':[True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False]})
```

for each row in df1 I would like to know its count in this df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['yes','yes','no','yes','no','yes','yes','no','no','no'],
                   'B':['L','M','M','L','M','M','H','L','H','M'],
                   'C':[True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False]})
```

By adding a column 'count' in df1, the expected output is the following:

```
index     A     B     C     count
0        yes    L   True        2
1        yes    L   False       0
2        yes    M   True        1
3        yes    M   False       1
4        yes    H   True        0
5        yes    H   False       1
6         no    L   True        0
7         no    L   False       1
8         no    M   True        2
9         no    M   False       1
10        no    H   True        0
11        no    H   False       1
```

May I know the pythonic way to do this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) of `df2` with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html). Last you can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html) with column for replacing `NaN` to `0` :

```
print df2.groupby(['A','B','C']).size().reset_index(name='count')
     A  B      C  count
0   no  H  False      1
1   no  L  False      1
2   no  M  False      1
3   no  M   True      2
4  yes  H  False      1
5  yes  L   True      2
6  yes  M  False      1
7  yes  M   True      1

print pd.merge(df1, 
               df2.groupby(['A','B','C']).size().reset_index(name='count'),
               on=['A','B','C'],
               how="left").fillna({'count': 0})

      A  B      C  count
0   yes  L   True      2
1   yes  L  False      0
2   yes  M   True      1
3   yes  M  False      1
4   yes  H   True      0
5   yes  H  False      1
6    no  L   True      0
7    no  L  False      1
8    no  M   True      2
9    no  M  False      1
10   no  H   True      0
11   no  H  False      1
```

Comment: I improve answer, because `fillna(0)` replace `NaN` in all `df` and is necessary replace `NaN` only in column `count`